# List of repeating element in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang

I can't find a way to use an Erlang library function to create a list consisting of an element E repeated N times. Sure, it's a cinch to write one,

```
repeat(E, N) ->
    repeat(E, N, []).
repeat(_E, 0, L) ->
    L;
repeat(E, N, L) ->
    repeat(E, N-1, [E|L]).
```

but I expected this to be a one-liner using some lists module function or something. Is there a way?

**Edit**: Ok, there's this of course,

```
lists:map(fun(_) -> E end, lists:seq(1, N))
```

but that creates an extra list that is immediately discarded. Seems inefficient to me, but maybe I'm not thinking Erlang-idiomatically.

**Edit 2**: Turns out it was a stupid question. I just somehow didn't see the *duplicate* function in the lists module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there is a function in erlang can do it:

```
lists:duplicate(N,X).

%% and repeat a string like this:
repeat(X,N) ->
    lists:flatten(lists:duplicate(N,X)).
```

Comment: Hm, why the flatten? Isn't duplicate exactly what I'm looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. I thought a repeat method of string.

Answer (score 4):

List comprehension would work too:

```
> [E || _ <- lists:seq(1,N)].
```